# How to handle real time GPS data with ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, gps, arcgis-9.3, chrome

I'm developing a web app using Arcgis Server 9.3.1 and Javascript API

I have a database with gps data from several vehicles and I need to display each vehicle real position in a map. I display this points in a Dynamic Layer, but I need to add an Identify action on hover, so I created a graphics layer, and every 10 seconds, I clear the graphics layer and query the database to get the new coordinates values, then, I create and add each point to the graphics layer, so I can hover over the features and ifentify them.

This is already working in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome this causes a memory overflow.

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: lets have some code

Comment: If you're tracking a large number of vehicles, you may have better luck creating a map service and adding it as a dynamic map layer instead of using the graphics layer.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did, seems like I didn't explain myself. I already edited my question, plase, have a look.

Comment: How many vehicle points are you dealing with? Is the memory overflow immediate, or does it take a refresh or two?

Comment: There are about 200 vehicles, in IE and Firefox the memory used is about 70 MB, when in Chrome it starts at 70 MB and each refresh increase it until it crashes.

Comment: @eiefai I am facing same problem..did you get the answer ?

Comment: Hi, We didn't resolve the issue completly, What we did was to remove all the redundat functions and such, and this helped a lot, but we told our users to use Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried the chrome's march 13 release? Does that release fix your issue?